# Count textarea characters when show up on the screen (previously hidden)

Tags: jquery

I have this HTML code :

```
<div id="mylist" class="row">
    <form>
        <select class="form-control">
            <option selected="selected" value="0">Please select</option>
            <option value="1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</div>


<div id="myform" class="row">
    <form>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="example"><span id="option-selected"></span></label>
            <textarea id="mymessage" class="form-control"></textarea>                       
            <div id="charNum"></div>
        </div>
      <button type="submit">Save</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

and I have this jQuery script :

```
<script>
function countChar() {
    var len = $('#mymessage').val().length;
    $('#charNum').text(len+' characters');
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myform").hide();
    $("#mylist select").on('change', function(){
        $("#myform").show();        
        if (selectedCampaignValue == 0){
            $("#myform").hide();
        }
    });

    countChar();
    $('#mymessage').change(countChar);
    $('#mymessage').keyup(countChar);
});
</script>
```

and here's some story about it :

- by default, `#myform` is hidden and only appears when some value on `#mylist` is selected.
- textarea `#mymessage` characters are perfectly count with `countChar()` function.

However, `countChar()` only start counting when I typed something on the textarea. NOT when `#myform` show on the screen when selected.

how to make `countChar()` immediately counting textarea `#mymessage` characters when it show (triggered by selection of `#mylist`)

thank you.

Comment: *how to make countChar() immediately counting textarea #mymessage characters when it show* Characters will be counted only after you enter some text right? What do you mean by start counting immediately when there are no characters in the textarea at all? seems to work fine here http://jsfiddle.net/sskf5muo/

Comment: just call the `countChar()` method once the `#myform` is made visible

Comment: Is something else setting value? If so you need to make sure you update after the value change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either trigger `countChar()` when you show `#myform`:

```
$("#mylist select").on('change', function(){
    $("#myform").show();        
    countChar();
    if (selectedCampaignValue == 0){
        $("#myform").hide();
    }
})
```

Or you could trigger `#mymessage`'s `change` event:

```
$("#mylist select").on('change', function(){
    $("#myform").show();        
    $("#mymessage").trigger("change");
    if (selectedCampaignValue == 0){
        $("#myform").hide();
    }
});
```

Either of these will accomplish what you're seeking, but I would suggest the first, as it's simpler and faster.

Comment: @RobertHanson No problem. This is unrelated, but it's worth noting that you are performing an unnecessary call with `$('#mymessage').keyup(countChar);`. jQuery's support of chaining causes most methods called on jQuery objects to return the object they were called on, so you can remove that line and replace the one above it with `$('#mymessage').change(countChar).keyup(countChar);`.

Answer (score 0):

Might be you have to change as per your given description

```
if ($(this).val() == 0){
       $("#myform").hide();
}
```

Instead Of

```
if (selectedCampaignValue == 0){
     $("#myform").hide();
 }
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0o26uoam/1/)**